# LinEst for polynomial function vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate a polynomial regression using vba. First, I tried y=x^2+b:

```
OUTPUT = WorksheetFunction.Application.LinEst (A,Application.Power(C,2),True,True)
```

where A and C are arrays
and the `OUTPUT` is good. I can read `r2` from `OUTPUT` using `Application.Index(OUTPUT,3)`

However, when I want to try `y=x+x^2+b` by adding Array to the argument of Array:

```
OUTPUT = WorksheetFunction.Application.LinEst (A,Application.Power(C,Array(1,2)),True,True)
```

I cannot read `r2` from `OUTPUT` using `Application.Index(OUTPUT,3)`

Any solution? What am I doing wrong?

---

Solution:
R_SQUARE = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, Application.Power(xVal, Application.Transponse(Array(1, 2))), True, True), 3,1)

Answer (score 2):

Try following ..

```
Sub LinEst()
Dim yVal As Range, xVal As Range
Set yVal = Range("C5:C14")
Set xVal = Range("B5:B14")

'You tried following formula which gives incorrect results for polynomial order 2
Range("B17") = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, 2), True, True), 3)

'For linear
Range("B18") = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                xVal, True, True), 3)
'For polynomial order 2
Range("B19") = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2)), True, True), 3)
'For polynomial order 3
Range("B20") = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, True), 3)

End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried with `=INDEX(LINEST({3,2,5,7,4,2,1,-2,-5,-1},{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TRUE,TRUE),3)` in worksheet. But in VBA i couldn't assign values to an array as double. But when tried @Domenic 's suggestion in comments below without data type it worked.

Following works.

```
Sub LinEst()
'Dim xVal(1 To 10) As Double, yVal(1 To 10) As Double 'This fails

xVal = Application.Transpose(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
yVal = Application.Transpose(Array(3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, -2, -5, -1))

'For polynomial order 3
Range("B20") = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, True), 3)

End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS!!! ohhh! I think that I figure out the problem. My xVal and yVal were not defined as "Range" but they were defined as: Dim xVal(1 to 10) as Double. The vba code fills xVal with values. Is it possible to convert my xVal array to the format that could be used by LinEst? Thanks again

Comment: @Ramon While the array orientation for both xvalues and yvalues need to be the same, the array orientation for the polynomials must differ from the xvalues and yvalues.  Therefore, as an example, for the polynomial order of 2, try `Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2))`.

Comment: I tried with `=INDEX(LINEST({3,2,5,7,4,2,1,-2,-5,-1},{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TRUE,TRUE),3)` in worksheet. But in VBA i couldn't assign values to an array as double. But when tried @Domenic 's suggestion without data type it worked. Thanks Domenic

Comment: @Domenic Thanks! Making progress, for sure! I used Application.Transpose and it works; however, a new problem appeared! I store the value of r2 in a variable as follows: R_SQUARE = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, Application.Power(xVal, Application.Transponse(Array(1, 2))), True, True), 3), but I cannot compare R_SQUARE with another numeric variable. For example, if I use  If R_SQUARE > 0 Then... I get an error. However, if I use Activecell.Value = R_SQUARE works perfectly and I get the r2 in the sheet. How can I compare R_SQUARE with a number in my code? THANKS!!!

Comment: R_SQUARE  is always positive so no need to check if it is >0. Also, I tried using  R_SQUARE  for further calculation within VBA but there is `type mismatch error` . Asking a question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242978/how-to-use-result-of-excel-function-vbarray-data-type-8204-for-further-calcu)

Comment: Thanks to FaneDuru . That question is solved. My mistake in the above answer .. It should be `Range("B20") = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, True), 3, 1)` .. If you think this answers your question please upvote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62243225/9808063)