# Using result of function ("vbArray" data type 8204) for further calculations

Tags: excel, vba

Refer [comments on answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226403/linest-for-polynomial-function-vba/62228131?noredirect=1#comment110075827_62228131). Result of `WorksheetFunction.LinEst` is ArrayVar(8204) data type (referred [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)). When I extract an element of the array to worksheet using `Application.Index`, it works fine. But, any further calculations on the same element results in type mismatch error.

Following is the VBA procedure used.

```
Sub LinEst()

xVal = Application.Transpose(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
yVal = Application.Transpose(Array(3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, -2, -5, -1))

rSQr = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, True), 3)

Debug.Print VarType(rSQr); TypeName(rSQr) 'Result is : 8204 Variant()

Range("B3") = rSQr 'Works fine; result is 0.818598661125351

'Debug.Print rSQr 'Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch
'rSQr = Round(rSQr, 6) 'Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch


End Sub
```

Please guide on how can we use rSQr for further calculations/ comparisons within VBA.

Thank you.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.LinEst` returns an array (describing a line). Try, please `Debug.print  rSQr(1), rSQr(2)`...

Comment: The rSqr is an array 5x4. You can reach all values as it is here for the first one:  rSqr(1,1). Try Debug.Print Round(rSqr(1, 1), 6). Should work.

Comment: Try also `Range("B3:C3") = rSQr`, in order to obtain a useful return...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please. `WorksheetFunction.LinEst` returns an array (describing a line):

```
Sub testLinEst()
 Dim xVal As Variant, yVal As Variant, rSQr As Variant, el As Variant
 xVal = Application.Transpose(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
 yVal = Application.Transpose(Array(3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, -2, -5, -1))

 rSQr = Application.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, True), 3)

 Debug.Print VarType(rSQr), rSQr(1), rSQr(2)

 Range("B3:C3") = rSQr 'Works fine
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh!! @FaneDuru .. Yes you are right. My silly mistake. I now realised I forgot to mention Column 1 to end appication.index Thanks. Its done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. At least it is working fine on my computer.
What I have done: include dim statements. Defined rSqr as variant and assign it to a range. Additionally I append the .Value to the range.

```
Sub LinEst()
    Dim xVal As Variant, yVal As Variant, rSqr As Variant
    xVal = Application.Transpose(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    yVal = Application.Transpose(Array(3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, -2, -5, -1))
    rSqr = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVal, _
                    Application.Power(xVal, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, True)
    Range("B3:E6").Value = rSqr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor . But as I mentioned, we can get values in worksheet. But, we can not use rSQr for further calculation/ comparison within VBA. It results in type mismatch error. Any idea how can we do that?