# vba LinEst worksheetfunction 2019

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I'm trying to loop a LinEst function in vba but it gives me error "Type mismatch"

```
For i = 2 to x
.Range("A" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SeriesSum(xVal_start, 3, -1, Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(y_range, Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(x_range, Array(1, 2, 3)), True, False))
next i
```

any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. See if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226403/linest-for-polynomial-function-vba) helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link, though i already saw this post and tried to follow i didn't notice that i just need to exclude literally the "Application" on "Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst" as well as for "WorksheetFunction" on "Application.WorksheetFunction.Power" in order for the code to work. Now it works fine.